# How to review my flags?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I was flagging a question, when I received this message from SO

Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please [review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3001736) them before flagging this post!

But, I found no option for reviewing. What should be done here?

Comment: Did you check the decline reasons below your flags?

Comment: In this context I believe that "reviewing" them just means that you need to take a look at them again and re-evaluate if the flags were really needed.

Comment: @3ventic Yes. I saw it

Comment: Then you have reviewed them. You know why your flags were declined, so you know to avoid flagging similarly again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the word "review" is highlighted as a link within that message. Do you not see that link?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, yeah I did that already. Nothing happened

Comment: @Lix: Thanks a lot, Stack Exchange - people are now associating the word "review" with actual pushing of buttons and increasing of numbers, and getting confused when there are none.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - "When intuitive design bites back."

Comment: I agree the wording is confusing. Hard to think of something better though.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Actually, I find the wording very natural (i.e. the use of the word "review" in this case), and I imagine a lot of other English-speaking users do too. It's the association that I mentioned that makes it seem confusing.

Comment: @Bolt indeed, that's why it's hard to find better word as "review" fits just fine... but already "reserved" to the review system.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that you go back to your flagging summary and check your declined flags. And try to understand why they are declined.

So you can cast flags that are valid in the future.

The number of flags you can cast each day depends on the overall validity of your flags.