# How can I review my flags?

Tags: support, flag-history

I got the following message when I tried to flag a question:

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

I have found a possible duplicate of this actual question, but it doesn't really answer it:

> [Too many of your recent flags declined, but not in reality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223364/too-many-of-your-recent-flags-declined-but-not-in-reality) (MetaSE Question)

Also, how can I review my flags? Maybe there wasn't really anything needed between them, but I think most of them were valid. My current statistic is 5 declined flags to 108 helpful.

---

Checking my flagging history isn't an answer to my question, because it doesn't help me to review my flags. It only shows my flagging history.

Comment: Checking you history IS reviewing your flags. It wants you to go look at the decline reasons so you know where you're going wrong.

Comment: In the case of disputed/helpful you don't get any additional feedback, but declined flags have a message attached, sometimes a canned one like "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it", or sometimes they are personalised. Either way you can then check the post to see why a moderator might not have agreed with your flag.

Comment: "Checking my flagging history isn't an answer to my question, because it doesn't help me to review my flags. It only shows my flagging history." http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226159/how-to-review-my-flags#comment739948_226159

Comment: Not sure you see the point I was making by linking to that comment. My point is that, as others have already said, checking your flags *is* reviewing them, because that's precisely what the dictionary definition of "reviewing" means. You go to your flag history, you study it, and find out where you went wrong. There are no buttons to press. It's not a tangible call-to-action. But of course given that Stack Exchange has an entire reviewing system that involves pressing of buttons it's probably no surprise that you were expecting to do something tangible when asked to "review" your flag history.

Comment: See also: [Where can I see my flag count / history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132018)

Answer (score 16):

Go to your profile and click on the *helpful flags* link. You will see the flagging history and be able to find out what was helpful and what was rejected.

This *helpful flags* link is currently located in the *Impact* box of the *Activity* tab of a profile.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: The answer is correct. Looking at your flag history counts as reviewing. The "review your flags" message will disappear after you get some helpful flags.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: That's strange. I was still able to flag posts when I got that message.

Comment: Where is the Helpful Flags link? Could you attach a screenshot? I found it earlier and now can't relocate it for the life of me.

Comment: Nevermind, got it

Comment: In this history, *declined* flag may have a complementary explanation. (Unfortunately this is not always the case, and as my first declined flag was having none, I was having the same question as the OP.)

Comment: What is review my flag's while i can't edit the flag i posted what is the use of this message??